# SwiftUI Picker does not respect frame size on device

Tags: ios, swiftui, frame, uipickerview, picker

My Picker view goes beyond the frame size only on device, while works fine in simulator. This view is not a part of a Form or List, just inside a VStack

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(title)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        Spacer()
        
        if isEditing {
            Picker(selection: $value) {
                Section {
                    Text("None").tag("None")
                }
                Section {
                    ForEach(Countries.all, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text(i).tag(i)
                    }
                }
            } label: {}
            .frame(height: DocumentPage.rowHeight) // <-- This is ignored 
        } else {
            // View when not editing
        }
        
    }
    .frame(height: DocumentPage.rowHeight) // <-- And this is ignored
}
```

On the Simulator vs. on device

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [.layoutPriority(1)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layoutpriority(_:)) on the Picker() and [.fixedSize()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()) on the Text() helped.